# Difference between 2 event handlers assignments

Tags: javascript

Assume we have a simple html-page with one script:

```
<html> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
window.onpopstate=function(event) 
{   alert("hi"); } 
</script> 
<body > 
<h1> Hi, 2 </h1> 
<a href="h3.htm">next</a> 
</body> 
</html>
```

It doesn't work (I tried under Chrome and FF). But when I write script code as

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function pp(event) {      alert("hi");    }
window.onpopstate=pp()
</script>
```

it works! As for me, theese two pieces of code differs only in function definition, but in practice it is not the same.

BTW, even if *onpopstate* event fires, *event* is undefined. It is one more unclear thing for me. Thank you for a help.

Comment: The second example executes `pp` immediately, attempting to assign the return value (*undefined* in this case) to `window.onpopstate`.

Comment: Use neither, `target.addEventListener(type, handler)` is your friend

Comment: @Sampson, now it is more clearly for me, thanks!

Comment: @Paul S, thank you, I'll try to do it tomorrow :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Sampson stated.. they are not the same...

On the second example, `window.onpopstate` is being populated with the **result** of the execution of `pp`. In this case, this function returns undefined so `window.onpopstate` is undefined after that. You see the `alert`, of course, but `window.onpopstate` is `undefined`.

On the first example, `window.onpopstate` is populated with the function itself, which is what's actually expected. If you see [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onpopstate), `onpopstate` expects a `funcRef`, which is exactly what you're passing in as argument.

Bottom line: On the second example you see the `alert` because you're calling the function but the first one is the correct one. In order to actually see the `onpopstate` being fired you should add to the browser history, but that's another story...

Comment: yep, you are right about "another story" - from my side, it look like I was a little hobbit, but now I'm in a center of great events :)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly in second snippet you have function call `pp()`, and you probabbly ment `window.onpopstate=pp`.

Secondly it works when you do manualy `history.pushState({page: 1}, "title 1", "?page=1");` and then `history.back();` or just click back button. No idea why clicking link don't add entry in history.